# How to close my model in a proper way

Tags: modeling, vertices

As on the image, I want to close his back and front but I don't want to look like a cube or plane.
I want how to it's details like belly,nose,mouth,eye and so on.
However I try, I can't add the vertices/lines so I can create details.
I just want to make a low poly orc, if you can help me out I would appreciate it a lot.
Thanks in advance and hope you respond. :)

(Sorry if I posted wrongly or something else since this is my first question)
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Grid Fill* option to create many faces.

Select the edge loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>), key <kbd>Space</kbd>, type *Grid Fill*, and select the option.

[image]

Example on a cylinder:

[image]

Comment: The question is duplicate of one already asked and answered. In this case do not add equal answer rather than mark question as a duplicate / add comment to question proposing link to the answered question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Comment: @MrZak I did flag immediately. I also decided to answer it, as to provide an easily accessible answer.

Comment: Answer is accessible via a linked duplicate. It is meant that nothing should be done except for flagging / commenting / voting.

Comment: @MrZak I just read those two meta questions. Two things: first, my answer on the linked question was not quite good enough, and you might notice that I improved upon it. Second, this is just kind of funny, it occurs to me that those questions are, well, duplicates.

Comment: I am sorry, I just didn't knew there was a question that is the exact like this one.
I couldn't find a question, I didn't knew how to search so I tried my own one.

Comment: @RenekThrope It's okay. Many, many people make that mistake. Just try not to make it twice. :) By the way, if my answer helped, please consider accepting it by selecting the checkmark in the top left of my answer. It would help me greatly!